# Is the axon part of a Schwann cell or no?

Tags: human-biology

Whenever I see diagrams of a neuron, it always shows the Shwann cells around the axon, but it doesn't seem as though anything distinguishes whether the axon is a component of the Schwann cells or not, or whether it's a component of the cell body itself (whatever that's called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, I think you have a bit of confusion in your use of terminology.

The axon is a part of a neuron, it's membrane is continuous with that of the cell body (also referred to as the 'soma'). Schwann cells are not neurons, they are a type of glial cell found in the peripheral nervous system. Schwann cells wrap their membrane around the outside of the axon to insulate it; this process or the presence of this insulation is called "myelination" and allows for faster transmission via saltatory conduction.

Cells that provide a similar function in the brain and spinal cord are called oligodendrocytes.

Comment: I think the fact that you just answered my question in detail proves it was clear enough. I asked if the axon is part of the Schwann cell, you clearly indicated "no" by explaining that the Schwann cell merely wraps around it and that the axon itself is an extension of the neuron. But despite that misunderstanding, thank you.